# How to show ToastEvent only when specific field on the opp changes?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

**Problem:** I have an LWC that is attached to an Opportunity and uses the `getRecord` method with the `@wire` decorator. This component is grabbing related information from a payment method that has been successfully linked to the opportunity. When the wire method detects the lookup-field is populated, it shows the ToastMessage. **TL&DR** It shows the toast message every time an opportunity loads, and I only need it to show when that field has a new record populated on it (i.e. null --> new record or old record --> new record)

```
//code for lwc 
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import {getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';


import OPPORTUNITY_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_METHOD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Related_Record__c';

const FIELDS = [
    OPPORTUNITY_RELATED_RECORD
];

export default class OppPaymentMethod extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@api recordId; //opp Id
    @api relatedRecordId;
    wiredOppResult; //stores the wired result and allows the refreshApex() to work correctly
    @track record;
    @track error;

@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS})
getOppRecord(result){
        this.wiredOppResult = result;
        let data = result.data;
        let error = result.error;
        if(data){
        if(this.relatedRecord.field.value == 'Pass'){
                    this.showToastSuccess();
     }

  }

//Additional methods ... 

}
```

Comment: Your description does not seem to match your code. The code will fire the toast whenever `@api` data passed into this component matches a condition (`this.relatedRecord.field.value == 'Pass'`). That is called each time the opportunity record is updated. What field on opportunity should be checked? It is not clear from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually looking at your code again, i `think` you want something like this:

```
import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS})
getOppRecord(result){
        let oldValue = this.wiredOpprResult == null ? null : getFieldValue(this.wiredOpprResult, OPPORTUNITY_RELATED_RECORD);

        let data = result.data;
        let error = result.error;
        if (data && oldValue !== getFieldValue(data, OPPORTUNITY_RELATED_RECORD)){
          this.showToastSuccess();
        }

        this.wiredOppResult = result;
  }
```

Comment: This was the kind of thing I was looking for. Going to test now and see what happens. I had also found a solution using a Set and passing the Ids into the set and checking for new ids during runtime.